Different output between Go exec.Command() and shell script vs direct terminal execution for CLAN kideval in Docker container
I'm maintaining a server for school but encountered a strange error after a version update Using Docker with Ubuntu:jammy as the operating system
The issue arose when the results of exec.command() in Go differed from directly entering commands in the terminal. The program in question is kideval, part of CLAN, which is related to children's language analysis. The command is roughly:
/app/unix-clan/unix/bin/kideval +lzho +t*CHI /app/cha_store/Chang1_01.cha
I initially thought I could solve this with a shell script, but it produced the same results as exec.command():
#!/bin/bash

KIDEVAL="/app/unix-clan/unix/bin/kideval"
CHA_STORE="/app/cha_store"

source ~/.bashrc

find "$CHA_STORE" -type f -name "*.cha" | while read -r file; do
    echo "Processing file: $file"
    "$KIDEVAL" +lzho +t*CHI "$file"
    
    echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): $file"
done

Direct terminal input:
root@cfe57a969458:/# /app/unix-clan/unix/bin/kideval +lzho +t*CHI /app/cha_store/Chang1_01.cha
    Using default, build into KIDEVAL source code, language file: zho
kideval +lzho +t*CHI /app/cha_store/Chang1_01.cha
Mon Oct 21 15:32:22 2024
kideval (27-Jan-2021) is conducting analyses on:
  ONLY speaker main tiers matching: *CHI;
    and those speakers' ALL dependent tiers
  and ALL header tiers
****************************************
From file <Chang1_01.cha>
Output file <Chang1_01.kideval.xls>

---

run ./script.sh or ./script.sh:
output:
...
****************************************
From file <Chang1_01.cha>
From file <Chang1_01.cha>
ERROR: No speaker matching +t option found
Output file <Chang1_01.kideval.xls>
    TIER "*CHI", ASSOCIATED WITH A SELECTED SPEAKER,
         HASN'T BEEN FOUND IN THE INPUT DATA!

Other programs process the data and then use this program to execute commands.
package utils

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

//RunCmd run a specify command and get its stdout as return
//note: it's a blocking function and non-thread safe
func RunCmd(cmd string, opts []string) string {
    return RunCmdDir(cmd, opts, "")
}

//Tried exec.Command("/app/unix-clan/unix/bin/kideval", "+lzho", "+t*CHI", "/app/cha_store/Chang1_01.cha") but it still doesn't work.
func RunCmdDir(cmd string, opts []string, dir string) string {
    cmdobj := exec.Command(cmd, opts...)
    if dir != "" {
        cmdobj.Dir = dir
    }
    println("running cmd:")
    fmt.Printf("%+v %+v\n", cmd, opts)
    cmdobj.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmdobj.Stderr = os.Stderr
    res, err := cmdobj.Output()
    if err != nil {
        println("errror when getting cmd output:", err.Error())
    }
    println("result\n", string(res))
    return string(res)
}

And this is the output of the above program.
 running cmd:
 /app/unix-clan/unix/bin/kideval [+lzho +t*chi /cha_store/Chang1_01.cha]
     Using default, build into KIDEVAL source code, language file: zho
 kideval +lzho +t*chi /cha_store/Chang1_01.cha
 Mon Oct 21 15:31:38 2024
 kideval (27-Jan-2021) is conducting analyses on:
   ONLY speaker main tiers matching: *CHI;
     and those speakers' ALL dependent tiers
   and ALL header tiers
 ****************************************
 From file </cha_store/Chang1_01.cha>
 From file </cha_store/Chang1_01.cha>
 
 ERROR: No speaker matching +t option found 
 Output file </cha_store/Chang1_01.kideval.xls> 
 
     TIER "*CHI", ASSOCIATED WITH A SELECTED SPEAKER,
          HASN'T BEEN FOUND IN THE INPUT DATA!

I'm not sure if this is a CLAN kideval issue since it worked before and hasn't been updated. We only updated the Go version and some unrelated programs. I've tried most solutions found online, such as modifying environment variables, setting character encoding, or configuring program paths. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to solve it?

if you're going to use a go tag, include Go code.  It looks like you've provided an example of the behavior you desire?  Please also include also the actual behavior you're seeing

The source .bashrc line is suspicious; you shouldn't normally need to re-read the current user's dotfile in a script.  The unquoted * also seems like a potential source of trouble.  In your Go code, are you missing some environment variables?  What path actually works?

Thank you for the reminder. I’ve uploaded the Go program and its output, and the actual behavior should be the same as when I enter the commands directly.

Your outputs show that the program executes, and even evaluates the arguments passed in which are echoed in the error message. The shell and Go output match, so this appears to be something specific to your kideval application and data.

(I second David Maze's comment) In your shell script: does commenting the source .bashrc line make the script work ? from the command line: does the same command work when you place quotes around "+t*CHI" ?
